# How to match list of characters with partial strings in R?

Tags: r

I am analysing IDs from the RePEc database. Each ID matches a unique publication and sometimes publications are linked because they are different versions of each other (e.g. a working paper that becomes a journal article). I have a database of about 250,000 entries that shows the main IDs in one column and then the previous or alternative IDs in another. It looks like this:

```
df$repec_id <– c("RePEc:cid:wgha:353", "RePEc:hgd:wpfacu:350","RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050")
df$alt_repec_id <– c("RePEc:sii:giihdizi:heidwg06-2019|RePEc:azi:cusiihdizi:gdhs06-2019", "RePEc:tqu:vishdizi:d8z7-200x", "RePEc:aus:cecips:15_59|RePEc:sga:leciam:c8wc0z888s|RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050", "RePEc:cid:wgha:353|RePEc:hgd:wpfacu:350")
```

I want to find out which IDs from the `repec_id` column are also present in the `alt_repec_id` column and create a dataframe that only has rows matching this condition. I tried to strsplit at "|" and use the `%in%` function like this:

```
df <- separate_rows(df, alt_repec_id, sep = "\\|") 
df1 <- df1[trimws(df$alt_repec_id) %in% trimws(df$repec_id), ]
df1<- data.frame(df1)
df1 <- na.omit(df1)
df1 <- df1[!duplicated(df1$repec_id),]
```

It works but I'm worried that by eliminating duplicate rows based on the values in the `repec_id` column, I'm randomly eliminating matches. Is that right?

Ultimately, I want a dataframe that only contains values in which strings in the `repec_id` column match the partial strings in the `alt_repec_id` column. Using the example above, I want the following result:

```
df$repec_id <– c("RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050")
df$alt_repec_id <– c("RePEc:aus:cecips:15_59|RePEc:sga:leciam:c8wc0z888s|RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050")
```

Does anyone have a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried inner join?

Comment: In the example you provide above, do any of the 3 rows match the criteria you're looking for?

Comment: None of them match. Would it be easier to understand if they did? Also, I haven't tried inner join. How would I use that here? Thank you both for your help!

Comment: See new example and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str_detect()` from `stringr` to identify if the `repec_id` exists in the larger `alt_repec_id` string.

Then `filter()` down to where it was found. This this is not returning as expected, try looking at and posting a few examples where `found_match == FALSE` but the match was expected.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(found_match = str_detect(alt_repec_id, repec_id)) %>% 
  filter(found_match == TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Just tried it. Unfortunately the result is way off (a df with 23 rows. It should be about 20,000). Could it be because many of the ids in df$alt_repec_id are separated by "|"?

Comment: It could be a few things. I will propose something else. The separator should not be the problem. At least it ran fast! Posting more data wouldn't hurt. This worked for the sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll post some more data now.

Comment: This is similar but might help you target problem records.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `grepl()` + `apply()` + `subset()`

```
dfout <- subset(df,apply(df, 1, function(v) grepl(v[1],v[2])))
```

such that

```
> dfout
              repec_id                                                            alt_repec_id
3 RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050 RePEc:aus:cecips:15_59|RePEc:sga:leciam:c8wc0z888s|RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(repec_id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("RePEc:cid:wgha:353", 
"RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050", "RePEc:hgd:wpfacu:350"), class = "factor"), 
    alt_repec_id = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("RePEc:aus:cecips:15_59|RePEc:sga:leciam:c8wc0z888s|RePEc:cpi:dynxce:050", 
    "RePEc:sii:giihdizi:heidwg06-2019|RePEc:azi:cusiihdizi:gdhs06-2019", 
    "RePEc:tqu:vishdizi:d8z7-200x"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hey, what does the first '1' represent here? Is that the first column or a new df?

Comment: @Oliver `1` means apply the function by row